# How to implement Create with child collection in Application Layer?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, repository-pattern, aspnetboilerplate

I have 2 entities named `News` and `NewsAttachment` in the **.Core** Project. These entities have a relationship through `News_Id`. In other words, when I create new `News` and add it into database, this `News` may have one or two attachment media that I want to insert in the related table named `NewsAttachment`. So I may want to retrieve `News_Id` and insert attachments in the related table.

I define 2 DTOs named `NewsDto` and `CreateNewsDto` in `NewsAppService` and I pass `CreateNewsDto` to insert new `News`, but I have no idea how to do it for `NewsAttachment`.

Here is my `News` entity:

```
public class News : FullAuditedEntity<long>
{
    public const int MaxTitleLength = 150;
    public const int MaxContentLength = 1200;
    public const int MaxMetaTagLength = 60;

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(MaxTitleLength)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(MaxContentLength)]
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public DateTime PublishDate { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(MaxMetaTagLength)]
    public string Tags { get; set; }

    public virtual NewsType Type { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<NewsAttachment> Attachments { get; set; }
}
```

and `NewsAttachment` entity:

```
public class NewsAttachment: FullAuditedEntity<long>
{
    public const int MaxTitleLength = 50;

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(MaxTitleLength)]
    public string FileName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public byte[] File { get; set; }
    public string FileExtension { get; set; }
    public int FileSize { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime RegisterDate { get; set; }

    public virtual News News { get; set; }
}
```

and the DTOs:

```
public class NewsDto : EntityDto<long>
{
    public const int MaxTitleLength = 50;
    public const int MaxContentLength = 800;
    public const int MaxMetaTagLength = 60;

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(MaxTitleLength)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(MaxContentLength)]
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public DateTime PublishDate { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(MaxMetaTagLength)]
    public string Tags { get; set; }

    public virtual NewsType Type { get; set; }
}
```

and:

```
public class CreateNewsDto
{
    public const int MaxTitleLength = 50;
    public const int MaxContentLength = 800;
    public const int MaxMetaTagLength = 60;

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(MaxTitleLength)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(MaxContentLength)]
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public DateTime PublishDate { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(MaxMetaTagLength)]
    public string Tags { get; set; }

    public virtual NewsType Type { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<NewsAttachment> Attachments { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my presumptive method in `NewsAppService` to insert new `News` and add related media to `NewsAttachment` table:

```
public virtual NewsDto InsertWithMedia(CreateNewsDto input, NewsAttachmentDto attach)
{
   var news = ObjectMapper.Map<NewsManagement.News>(input);

    var newsAttachment = ObjectMapper.Map<NewsAttachment>(attach);
    newsAttachment.News.Id = news.Id;
    return MapToEntityDto(news);
}
```

Comment: i add extra code for my scenario @aaron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two choices:

1. Add to `ICollection` and let EF handle the entities:

```
public virtual NewsDto InsertWithMedia(CreateNewsDto input, NewsAttachmentDto attach)
{
    var news = ObjectMapper.Map<NewsManagement.News>(input);
    news.Attachments = new List<NewsAttachment>(); // 1

    var newsAttachment = ObjectMapper.Map<NewsAttachment>(attach);
    news.Attachments.Add(newsAttachment);          // 2

    _newsRepository.Insert(news);                  // 3
    CurrentUnitOfWork.SaveChanges();               // 4

    return MapToEntityDto(news);
}
```

2. Add by `Id` instead of collection, with a foreign key:

```
public class NewsAttachment: FullAuditedEntity<long>
{
    // ...

    public virtual long NewsId { get; set; }
    public virtual News News { get; set; }
}
```

```
public virtual NewsDto InsertWithMedia(CreateNewsDto input, NewsAttachmentDto attach)
{
    var news = ObjectMapper.Map<NewsManagement.News>(input);
    var newsId = _newsRepository.InsertAndGetId(news); // 1

    var newsAttachment = ObjectMapper.Map<NewsAttachment>(attach);
    newsAttachment.NewsId = newsId;                    // 2

    _newsAttachmentRepository.Insert(newsAttachment);  // 3
    CurrentUnitOfWork.SaveChanges();                   // 4

    return MapToEntityDto(news);
}
```

The second is good for updating — when `newsId` is already known — but may require additional steps if `NewsDto` also has `Attachments` (which should be `ICollection<AttachmentDto>` type).

Comment: thank you @aaron . I have another question. should I define NewsId in NewsAttachmentDto and CreateNewsAttachmentDto in addition to the NewsAttachment entity in application layer? for example in front end I define Viewmodel to show last news and I want to add picture of each news to them.

Comment: You should define `CreateNewsAttachmentDto` for a consistent abstraction. The `NewsId` in `NewsAttachmentDto` depends if you actually need that on client side. For example, if you only get attachments by `newsId` then having it in the DTO has no value. But if you can query all attachments, then it may be useful to know which `News` an attachment belongs to.

Comment: thank you @aaron very much for helping me. I fix it  temporary and I test another approach for that. but now there is no problem.

Answer (score 0):

thank you @aaron. after all, I have a little problem. in **.WebMpa** project how can I retrieve News with related picture.I define NewsViewModel in model folder and Map this ViewModel to NewsDto with Auto Mapper library.and in NewsController  call NewsAppService and GetAll method for get news from database.I have 2 Scenario for this situation:
1- I think that change this method in **.Application** Project and add some linq query to get News with related Pictures from NewsAttachment 
2- all operation about News and NewsAttachment and join with two entity stay in **.WebMpa** project and NewsController.
I confused really.would you help me with show example?

Comment: The first option is preferable. (This should be edited into your question instead of posted as a question. Show current code and what's not working.)